# ntpd distributes time before it has synchronized

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, ntp

I am running ntpd on raspberry pi 3. A number of sensors (esp8266 based) are getting time from said server. After power failure the pi reboots and starts ntpd. The sensors request time synchronization and ntpd responds with wrong time as it has not yet synchronized. Is there a way to prevent ntpd to respond before it has actually synchronized?
Logs on the pi show that the time is not correct, jumps to the correct value after 3-5 mins, so this behaviour is not be caused by the sensor software.
ntpd is started with the -g option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a discussion on the ntp irc channel. It seems there is no way to prevent ntpd from responding to client requests until synchronization is achieved. Their opinion is that it is the client's responsibility to ignore the ntp packet if the clock has not synchronized. Therefore one either has to change the esp8266 software or prevent ntpd responses using iptables. I have used the second method and included the following in rc.local:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport ntp -m iprange --src-range 10.0.200-10.0.0.250 -j DROP
if /usr/sbin/ntp-wait
   then
       /usr/bin/sudo iptables -D INPUT -p udp --dport ntp -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.200-10.0.0.250 -j DROP
fi
```